Error in accessing label file in Azure Language Studio - "This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission"
I am practising this tutorial. I am stuck at step 11 where I have to provide the JSON which has the labels:


In Blob storage container, choose language-studio-training-data.
Select Yes, my documents are already labeled and I have a correctly formatted JSON labels file.
In Label documents, choose movieLabels.


I don't see the JSON file in dropdown. The error seems to be This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission. .I don't think it's networking issue as the storage can be accessed by all networks.
What I might be doing wrong?


I had to provide the Storage Blob Data Contributor role to the storage account
